# htc files: Why not to use them?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am developing a web application that aims to give a desktop feeling for the end user. That means I need a cross-browser feeling to the application (who doesn't? eheh).

So, I found about .htc files, for working around some IE tweaks (doesn't support border-radius yet, for example). My doubt is: Why isn't everyone using them? Does it come with some problems I am ignoring? From the place I am seeing, it appears to be almost the holy grail for the front-end programmers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Components):

> HTML Components (HTCs) are a
>   nonstandard mechanism to implement
>   components in script as Dynamic HTML
>   (DHTML) "behaviors"[1] in the
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer web
>   browser. Such files typically use an
>   .htc extension.
>
> An HTC is typically an HTML file (with
>   JScript / VBScript) and a set of
>   elements that define the component.
>   This helps to organize behavior
>   encapsulated script modules that can
>   be attached to parts of a Webpage DOM.

In two paragraphs, the following are mentioned:

- Internet Explorer
- JScript
- VBScript
- nonstandard

I think it's obvious why not everybody is using this technology.

Comment: How is this any different from using non standard extentions such -moz or -webkit?

Comment: Because nonstandard CSS prefixes like -moz or -webkit don't break the entire application if you try to use it in other browsers than IE.  HTC only works in IE...

Comment: @Doug So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[How to use border-radius.htc with IE to make rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074950/how-to-use-border-radius-htc-with-ie-to-make-rounded-corners/4074987#4074987)

> The server has to server the HTC with the correct MIME type (text/x-component)

That alone is enough to stop JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery or MooTools from being able to use them. The dependency on configuring anything a server in order to get client-side functionality working is beyond unacceptable.

It's a real pity though, htc files really are capable of a lot of interesting things.