# How do I include a PHP url in a CSS file?

Tags: php, css

I have link to an extended version of [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) within php ([codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)):

```
<link href="<?= base_url() . RESOURCE_PATH . 'css/extended_bootstrap.' ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In my CSS file I have:

```
input[type="file"]
{
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

But the url to [**PIE.htc**](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/) hast to be relative to the [root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912587/twitter-bootstrap-cross-browser-rounded-corners-and-gradients). How do I format the url so it is relative to root and not my extended version of bootstrap.css?

Comment: Start it with a leading slash `/` – that points to your domain root.

Comment: Its not possible to include a working PHP url in CSS file, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `../` to move "up" a level.  You can tie these together to move multiple levels.

For example...

```
ROOT --> CSS --> style.css
ROOT --> pie.htc
```

To move back a level you would use `../pie.htc`

Answer (score 0):

if your folder structure is:

```
YourAppFolder/
    application/
           public/
               css/
               img/
         system/
```

Then use this in your views:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>public/css/style.css"/>
```

and in css use this for image:

```
background:#356aa0 url(../img/background.png) repeat-x;
```