# Borders, drop shadow and rounded corners in IE possible?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

There's a template setup that uses jQuery to apply styles after page load, for example:

```
$(".section").css("color","#000000");
```

and it changes background images, borders, etc.

Right now the sections have a border, background color, drop shadow and border radius for rounded corners.

Is it possible to make these work in IE?  I've tried liquid canvas and other rounding methods but I can't seem to

1. Get it to work at all because of the jQuery overrides.
2. Get all three to work at the same time in IE (border, drop shadow and rounded corners)

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I have the same problem regarding rounded corners in internet explorer, though I unfortunately wasn't able to fix it.  Meh, I use Firefox anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "rounded corners".

If you're talking about rounding corners using the css3 border-radius, then IE9 supports it, but not IE8 and IE7.  Firefox, Chrome, and Safari do support it, but you have to use their moz/webkit stuff to do so.

The easiest ways to get rounded corners in IE without using css, would be to use a background image and sprites.  So you actually have an image somewhere of your button, and you set that as the background on a span, div, or anchor tag.

There are also javascript libraries out there which draw rounded corners as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074950/how-to-use-border-radius-htc-with-ie-to-make-rounded-corners

Answer (score 1):

CSSPIE will do what you want.  It emulates some of these css3 features through a css3 behavior that you load.

http://css3pie.com

I've only seen it used and it might cause a slight performance hit, but it seems worth a try.  The nice thing about this method is it doesn't rely on JavaScript or IE specific images, etc.